# Name of theorem about replaceability of $i$ with $-i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I recall, many years ago, reading that an true equation remains true if at all instances within the equation, one changes $i$ to $-i$ and $-i$ to $i$, however I cannot remember what this is called, or if it even has a name.

If anyone is aware, I would appreciate - a fair bit of googling has not given any answers yet.

Comment: Complex Conjugation

Comment: You may be thinking of the [Complex Conjugate Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20complex%20conjugate,also%20a%20root%20of%20P.).

Comment: $\mathbb R(i)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R(-i)$; [the operation of complex conjugation is a field automorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Conjugation_is_Automorphism) of $\mathbb C$